# Putting together a business case for moving to git from TFS?

Tags: git, management, team-foundation-server, presentation

I'm probably going to be giving a presentation to my company (mainly management, but also senior developers) on the benefits of moving to Git from a centralized TFS setup.  I know that I massively prefer Git because of its speed and IMHO the improved workflow of the easy branching model, but what are the best (most convincing) arguments you have found to persuade people to at least trial a transition to Git, even if it's just for a small part of the project (like, one solution in Visual Studio containing a small number of files)?

I'd appreciate any tips you have that I could include in the presentation to provide a compelling set of arguments for transitioning to Git.  Especially now that TFS2013 has good support and integration for Git repos, there should be even fewer arguments against transitioning to Git.

In particular, I need to provide a business case for the switch.  Any tips on providing a business case would also be welcome.

Comment: recommended reading: **[How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)**

Comment: How this question counts as "too broad" is beyond me.  I'm clearly specifying what I need.  The desire to close questions on here is really overzealous nowadays.  :-(

Comment: Not what you asked, but does this help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013.aspx